# An std::function in a class that is set to a function in a class that contains the first class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Note: this question was edited in a way that is more related to the intend of the question from the first place.

Here is the code:

```cpp
class SmallClass
{
public:
    std::function<void(SmallClass*)> function;
};

class BigClass
{
public:
    SmallClass smallClass;

    void SomeFunction(SmallClass* smallClassP)
    {
        return;
    }

    BigClass()
    {
        smallClass.function = SomeFunction; // error
    }
};
```

This doesn't work. Using visual studio it will say "no operator matches these operands | operand types are: std::function<void (SmallClass*)> = void (SmallClass*)". By writing `std::bind(&BigClass::SomeFunction, this, &smallClass)`, it weirdly corrupts `smallClass` and sets it to NULL. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Edited to have a SmallClass* input in SomeFunction

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit; your question should remain strictly a question. Also, please refrain from using all upper case; this is perceived as rude SHOUTING.

Answer (score 5):

Because `SomeFunction` acturally has a invisible argument called 'this'.

Write like this:

```cpp
smallClass.function = std::bind(&BigClass::SomeFunction, this);
```

or use lambda:

```cpp
smallClass.function = [this]() { SomeFunction(); };
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I realized the example I gave is not fully accurate to my real situation - SomeFunction should have had a SmallClass* input.